# TypeScript pass an array as argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to send an simple array of strings to an function that might take no arguments, but Typescript complains with

```
`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[] | undefined'`
```

On the parent I have

```
// Default array if there is no argument on the submitArray function
const exisistingArray = ['string', 'string', 'string']

// Accept an array otherwise use another exisiting one
const submitArray = (array = exisistingArray) => { 
  console.log(array)
}

// I then pass the function to the children component
return (
  <Component submitArray={submitArray} />
)
```

And on the component

```
const data = [{
 "first": ['string', 'string', 'string']
},{
 "second": ['string', 'string', 'string']
}]

type Props = {
 submitArray: (array?: string[]) => void
}

export const Component = ({ submitForm }: Props) => {

  return (
     <ul>
       <li onClick={() => submitArray()>No argument</li>
       { data.map((entry, index) => (
          // I get the error here on the argument for the function
         <li key={index} onClick={() => submitArray(Object.values(entry)[0])}>
           {Object.keys(entry).join()}
         </li>
       ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I don't understand why if doing `Object.values(entry)[0]` on the `data` array, that gives me a plain array of strings, is not working, whereas if I do `Object.values(entry)` which is and array of strings inside an array does.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? What is `existingArray`?

Comment: `existingArray` is a default array in case I pass no array, but is not important, the problem is with the array I do pass, I am getting the error if I do `Object.values(entry)[0]` as the argument, but no error if I do `Object.values(entry)` but this gives me this `[['string', 'string', 'etc']]`

Comment: could you create a sandbox with the reproducible error. It seems that the data array doesn't have proper format of data which is why it gives you the error

Comment: Actually it's really weird, it seems the example I put works, in the real project I am getting the array from node by reading a json file, and even thou it looks the same then it fails

Comment: @Shubham Khatri you sent me on the right direction it turn out changing the json structure helped

Comment: `Object.values(entry)[0]` should resolve to the first element in the array, a `string` rather than the array of strings itself. It makes total sense then why `Object.values(entry)` is working for you

Comment: Don't edit the solution to the question. I've rolled back your last edit. Instead, post it as an answer to the question (yes, [it's OK to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the array to

```
const data = [{
  name: 'first',
  values : ['string', 'string', 'string']
},{
  name: 'second',
  values : ['string', 'string', 'string']
}]
```

And then it worked well with

```
export const Component = ({ submitForm }: Props) => {

  return (
     <ul>
       <li onClick={() => submitArray()>No argument</li>
       { data.map((entry, index) => (
         <li key={index} onClick={() => submitArray(entry.values)}>
           {entry.name)}
         </li>
       ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```